# Format value entered in input text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one  input text box  for  amount .I want to  format  user entered value . 
If user  enter value 8 then it should display it as 0.08
if user enter  89   it  should  display 0.89. and so on
and for  0 it should display 0.00

**********EDIT************************
I want to calculate on keyup  (when user type inputs)

Comment: Call a js / jQuery method to calculate (value / 100) on blur of field.

Comment: @saurabh, What about value > 100 or 1000?

Comment: @ParkashKumar  if  user enter  more than 100 , let`s say  127 it will be displayed as 1.27

Comment: Why do want to call it on keyup? Wouldn't value be disturbed on each key pressed?

Comment: @saurabh can you tell me what will become the result if i add a 5 in the input box contening 12.34 , 1234.4, or 123.0423 ?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a javascript method and call it on `onblur` of field, which will calculate and reset value as following:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="pointValue" onBlur="calculateFractionPoint(this);" />
```

**JS:**

```
function calculateFractionPoint(obj){
    var value = parseInt(obj.value);

    if(isNaN(value) && !isFinite(value)){
        alert("Number is not valid!");
        obj.value = "";
        return;
    }

    if(value === 0)
        obj.value = "0.00";
    else
      obj.value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2) / 100;   
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/83yvytcg/)

Comment: you can add if(!isNaN(parseInt(this)) && isFinite(n)) to check if it is a number or not to make it complete

Comment: If we pass this.value then we will need to get element to set value back.

Comment: Also, I have asked OP for additional conditions.

Comment: I have updated to check if number is valid and finite.